# Regarding opinion based questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Writers.stackexchange.com ~ The first thought that came to my mind was discussing opinion based questions here like - "How do I start an essay?" which other English speaking stackexchange communities like ELU and ELL do not address.

Most topics that require any help (in my case) are opinion based questions, but asking them will only result in disappoint and possibly a few negative votes.

If I wanted to ask a definitive question regarding the language, eg- word choices, or attractive idioms/phrases, then why wouldn't I consult something like english.stackexchange.com which (I do not mean any offense here) have a bigger community and a faster chance of response?

So basically, what I wanted to suggest was that opinion based questions should be allowed on writers to some extent, which would mean closing/putting on hold questions that are entirely or too much opinion based vs slightly opinion based ones.

For example, Question- "Can someone suggest me a couple of phrases when starting a formal letter" is slightly opinion based but is very much answerable and has potential to help the community and thus should be allowed.

Versus - "I want to start a short story but I don't know what I should write.. help please?" - such questions be closed off immediately.

Comment: Writing is a very subjective craft, and Writers.SE absolutely accepts subjective questions, as per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ . If you can point to some recent questions closed/downvoted for subjectivity, that'd be helpful.

Comment: That being said, we've got lots of _other_ reasons to close or downvote questions. We've evolved our scope gradually over time. We get a _lot_ of questions asking "what should I write," asking "please rephrase this passage for me," asking "how can I write a novel" (akin to "how can I code a program?"). Those aren't closed because they're subjective; they're closed because they're either unanswerable, or of no possible interest to anybody except OP.